# How to understand (solve) if group belong to set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let's say that N is a universal group. For every $n \in N$ marked that $ A_n = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} $. For each of the groups the following, determine whether they are equal or all of the groups $N, N \setminus \{0\}, \varnothing $

$$ \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(A_{n+1} \cap A_{n}^c) $$

How to solve it? Give me direction please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A_{n+1}= \{0,1,2,\dots,n,n+1\}
\\
A_n^c = \{0,1,2,\dots,n\}^c = \{n+1,n+2,\dots\}
\\
A_{n+1} \cap A_{n}^c = \{n+1\}
\\
\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(A_{n+1} \cap A_{n}^c) = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\{n+1\}
=\{1,2,3,\cdots\} = N\setminus \{0\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! But could you please share some links where I can read(maybe get practice) how to solve such expressions? Because I have more like this...